# What is the distance between the lighthouse and the boat on its new location?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have homework and I need to draw a representation of the problem to solve it.

"From a boat sailing due East, a lighthouse is observed at a bearing of 050° degrees. After sailing for 6.5 km, the same lighthouse has a bearing of 025° degrees from the boat. Find the distance between the lighthouse and the present position of the boat."

So far, this is the representation that I came up with:
[image]

$B_1$ represents the original location of the boat. $B_2$ represents the current location of the boat after sailing for 6.5 km. $L$ represents the lighthouse. I attempted to solve the problem by finding $DB_2$:

$\angle{LB_1C}=40°$

$\tan(40°)=\frac{DB_2}{6.5}$

$DB_2=\tan(40°)(6.5)$

$DB_2\approx 5.76$

This is where I got stuck. I don't know what else to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What will you do with $DB_2$ ? You are asked to find out $LB_2$, and you can easily know all the angles of triangle  $LB_1B_2$, and the length $B_1B_2$. And then ... ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Does that mean my representation is correct? If that's the case, then $\angle{LB_2B_1}=115°$ and $\angle{B_1LB_2}=25°$. Therefore, I can use the Law of Sines to solve for $LB_2$. Is this the correct conclusion?

Comment: Yes, go ahead !

Comment: @trueblueanil Thanks! Therefore,


$\frac{6.5}{\sin(25°)}=\frac{LB_2}{\sin(40°)}$; 

$(LB_2)(\sin(25°))=(6.5)(\sin(40°))$; 


$LB_2=\frac{(6.5)(\sin(40°))}{\sin(25°)}$; 


$LB_2 \approx 9.88 km$

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to check your calculations step by step ! You should have the confidence to do it on your own, given  the clear hints.

Comment: hint: You could work out the equation for the opp and adj of large triangle LCB1 and the same for the smaller triangle LCB2. Since both triangles have side LC in common it is easy to cancel out LC and find length CB2. Fairly easy from there...